# <Precise Proof> Every non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ which is bounded above(below) has a least upper bound(greatest lower bound)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

**Problem_**

> Every non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ which is bounded above(below) has a least upper bound(greatest lower bound).

I searched the proofs for the problem, and there were two. However, both proofs had some problems for me to understand.

The first proof I've found was:

> Let $S \subseteq\mathbb R$ and let $a_0$ be the largest integer that is a lower bound for $S$. Let $a_1$ be the largest integer between $0$ and $9$ for which $a_0.a_1$ is a lower bound for $S$. Then, generally, let $a_n$ be the greatest integer between $0$ and $9$ for which $a_0.a_1a_2\dots a_n$ is a lower bound for $S$. We claim that $$\lambda=a_0.a_1a_2\dots$$
>   is the greatest lower bound.
>
> First, we show that $\lambda$ is a lower bound. If not, there $\exists s\in S$ such that $s\lt\lambda$. By Archimedes' condition, there $\exists n\in\mathbb N$ such that $10^{-n}\lt\lambda-s$. Therefore, $a_n$ can be reduced by $1$ in the definition of $\lambda$; or, if $a_n=0$, some earlier $a_m\gt0$ can be reduced by $1$. **But this contradicts the definition of $\lambda$.**
>
> Then, we show that every lower bound $\mu$ is less than or equal to $\lambda$. If not, $\mu\gt\lambda$, so by Archimedes' condition, there $\exists n\in\mathbb N$ such that $10^{-n}\lt\mu-\lambda$. Therefore, $a_n$ can be increased by $1$ in the definition of $\lambda$; or, if $a_n=9$, some earlier $a_m\lt9$ can be increased by $1$. **But this contradicts the definition of $\lambda$.**

My question from here is **where the definition of $\lambda$ makes the contradiction?** I think I'm having confusion due to the lack of explanation about the definition of $\lambda$ and the reason for the contradiction. Could you please explain this?

The other proof I've got was:

> Let $A$ and $\mathcal L$ be any non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ bounded above and a set of all upper bounds of $A$. Suppose that $sup(A)$ does not exist. In other words, $\forall y\in\mathcal L, \exists y'\in\mathcal L$ such that $y'\lt y$. Therefore, $\forall x\in A$ and $\forall y\in\mathcal L, x\lt y$.
>
> If $\exists c$ such that $\forall y\in\mathcal L, c\lt y$ and $\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb R^+, \exists y\in A$ such that $y − c \lt\epsilon$, then $c\notin A$ or $c$ becomes least upper bound. However, **this implies that c is an upper bound, contradicting the existance of such c.**
>
> Then, if $\exists c_0 \in\mathbb R$ such that $\exists\epsilon\in\mathbb R^+, \forall y\in\mathcal L, c_0\lt y$ and $y − c_0\gt\epsilon$, construct $c_1 = c_0 + \epsilon$. For such $c_n$ satisfying conditions of $c_0$, construct $c_{n+1}$ in the same manner. If no such $\epsilon$ exists, let $c_{n+1} = c_n$. Let $c = \lim_{n\to\infty}c_n$. The constant $c$ clearly exists, because each element in the sequence is bounded above by any elements in $\mathcal L$ and the sequence is nondecreasing. This number acts the same way as the constant $c$ described above. Therefore, $\forall c\in\mathbb R, \exists y\in\mathcal L$ such that $y\lt c$. This concludes that $\forall x\in A$ and $\forall c\in\mathbb R, x\lt c$. Therefore, $A$ is empty,
>   contradicting the assumption that $A$ is a non-empty set.

The second proof was harder to understand than I expected. Even though I read this over 20 times, I'm still confusing about the flow of the proof, such as the **roles of $c$, and the reason that the author define $c_0$ again after defining $c$.** Besides, the part that the time is mostly devoted to accept is marked as bold: **why does $c$ imply "upper bound"?** Is there some typo? I deeply focused on this part, but it remains unsolved.

I really appreciate having your ideas. It's fine to answer one of those questions, though it would be perfect when you answer all! Thanks:)

Comment: What is your definition/understanding of the real numbers? In order to prove basic properties about the real numbers, we need to know how you have conceptualized the real numbers. Are the real numbers "decimal expansions"? Are they equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences? Are they Dedekind cuts? This may be important, because the Least Upper Bound property can be taken as part of the *definition* of real numbers, depending on your construction, and what is and what is not a valid proof depends on what you assume and what you must instead establish.

Comment: I just started the elementary process, and thanks for your advice! I have a question then, just for curious. Do you mean that depending on which definition of real numbers an individual has, the proof can be written in a different way?

Comment: depending on the definition, the proof *will* be different in this case. As I said, you can define the real numbers in such a way that this property is part of the **definition** of the set of real numbers, so that the “proof” would just say “by definition.” If the real numbers are constructed as Dedekind cuts, then the proof consists of taking the union of the (left sets) cuts in the set and then proving you get a cut. If the real numbers are constructed as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, then you have to construct a Cauchy sequence to realize the supremum. Different proofs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First proof:**

*In general:* The author defines $\lambda$ through its decimal expansion. So, when she writes that $\lambda=a_0.a_1a_2\ldots$, she means that $\lambda=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n10^{-n}$. Also, $a_n$ is defined iteratively for $n>0$ through
$$a_n=\max\left\{m\in\{0,1\ldots,9\}: \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i\cdot10^{-i}+m\cdot10^{-n}\leq s \text{ for all }s\in S\right\}.$$

*First contradiction:* Define $\lambda_n= a_0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n$. Now, from the definition of $a_n$ it should be clear that $\lambda_n\leq s$ for any $s\in S$. Also, notice that 
$$0\leq\lambda-\lambda_n\leq 10^n\qquad\text{for all }n.\qquad(1)$$
 Assume $\lambda$ is not a lower bound of $S$. Therefore, there exists $s\in S: s<\lambda$. 
Now, let $N$ be the *smallest* natural number such that $\lambda-s>10^{-N}$ (this is well-defined). We have that
$$\lambda-10^{-N}>s\geq \lambda_N\Rightarrow \lambda-\lambda_N>10^{-N}$$
which contradicts (1).

*Second contradiction:* I think you need to think similarly and take into account that $a_n$ is the **largest** digit that satisfies $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i\cdot10^{-i}+m\cdot10^{-n}\leq s \text{ for all }s\in S$.

Comment: I got the point! I can now know why the contradiction occurs. Thanks:D

Answer (score 1):

For the first proof, let me try to give more detail about what $\lambda$ is. We are given that $S$ is bounded below, so there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x<s$, for all $s\in S$. There are always integers less than $x$, so there exist integers which are also lower bounds for $S$. However $S\neq\varnothing$, so there exists $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $z$ is not a lower bound for $S$. Then the set $Z_0:=\{z\in\mathbb{Z}:z<s,\forall s\in S\}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is bounded above. Since the elements are integers, we know that $Z_0$ must have a maximal element.

Let $a_0:=\max(Z_0)$. This will be the integer part of our greatest lower bound $\lambda$. Next we move to the $10^{th}$'s place. The set $\{a_0,a_0+\frac{1}{10},a_0+\frac{2}{10},\cdots,a_0+\frac{9}{10}\}$ is finite, and contains a lower bound for $S$, namely $a_0$. So pick $a_1\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ maximal such that $a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}$ is a lower bound for $S$.

Similarly, there is a maximal lower bound for $S$ in the set $\{a_0+\frac{a_1}{10},a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{1}{100},a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{2}{100},\ldots,a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{9}{100}\}$. Let $a_2\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,0\}$ be maximal such that $a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{100}$ is a lower bound for $S$.

We can continue this process: For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, pick $a_n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$ maximal such that $a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{100}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{10^n}$ is a lower bound for $S$. Define $\displaystyle{\lambda:=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{10^n}}$.

Now we want to show that $\lambda$ is a lower bound, so we assume contrary. If there exists $s\in S$ such that $\lambda>s$, then $\lambda-s>0$. Hence by the Archimedian Principle, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lambda-s>\frac{1}{10^n}$. Rearranging, we have $\lambda-\frac{1}{10^n}<s$. But $\lambda-\frac{1}{10^n}=a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{100}+\cdots+\frac{a_n-1}{10^n}+\cdots <s$. So that means that $a_0+\frac{a_1}{10}+\frac{a_2}{100}+\cdots+\frac{a_n-1}{10^n}$ is a lower bound for $S$. However, we defined $a_n$ to be the *maximal* digit with this property, which gives us our contradiction.

Note that there is the slight issue of if $a_n=0$ since then $a_{n}-1=-1\notin\{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$. However this isn't actually a problem since then we carry to the previous digit which itself must have been maximal. If that digit was also  $0$, then we keep carrying until we eventually reach our contradiction.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for giving clear explanation! I have a question: what's the part 'rearranging' means? I cannot understand the part where it goes from $\lambda-s\gt10^{-n}$ to $\lambda-10^{-n}\lt s$? Thanks.

Comment: Add $s$ to both sides, then subtract $10^{-n}$ from both sides.

Comment: I mean, the direction of the inequality.